# Error resolving module specifier: dist/mathlive.mjs - как исправить эту ошибку?

Tags: javascript, html

Хочу сделать локальный html-файл, использующий JS библиотеку [MathLive](http://mathlive.io/).

В соответствии с [документацией](http://docs.mathlive.io/tutorial-USAGE_GUIDE.html) скачал эту библиотеку, и в её папке сделал такой html-файл:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/mathlive.core.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/mathlive.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="module">
            import MathLive from 'dist/mathlive.mjs';
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Папка dist лежит рядом с этим файлом. Однако при открытии этого файла браузер выдает такую ошибку:

> TypeError: Error resolving module specifier: dist/mathlive.mjs test.html:9:33

Подскажите, в чём может быть дело?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй сделать без import а напрямую вставь код из файла в твой HTML документ. И убедись что скрипт может работать локально без запросов на сервер. Если для работы скрипта нужны запросы на сервак то локально не получится.